# React app can't reach to backend python application on localhost on same server

Tags: python, reactjs, django, rest, cors

I have a public cloud VM which has public IP say `160.159.158.157` (this has a domain registered against it).
I have a Django application (backend) which is CORS-enabled and serves data through port 8080.
I have a React app running on the same VIM on a different port (3000), which is accessing the Django app and is supposed to produce a report.

The problem is that, when I use `http://<domain-name>:8080/api/` or `http://<public-ip>:8080/api/`, my application is working fine,
but when I try to fetch data from localhost like `http://localhost:8080/api/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/`, the React app fails to fetch data with the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Here's what I've tried:

```js
axios.get(baseURL, { headers: { 
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
}
```

but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Take the time to read and understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: You claim that your backend is "CORS-enabled". Edit your question and add your backend's CORS configuration. This is crucial information if you're hoping to get help.

Comment: Also, adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers to a request is useless; those are _response_ headers.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you've gotten confused where those headers need to be. You're setting them on the *request to* the backend, but they need to be set on the *response from* the backend. After all, it wouldn't be very good security if someone making a request could simply say "yeah, I'm ok, you should trust me".

The problem is going to be somewhere in your backend Django app, so double check the CORS config over there.

Comment: Thanks for answering,  first of all security isn't a concern for me as of now, first I tried without adding allow-cors-origin that didn't work too, and surprisingly why requests are not reaching to django backend as I can't see any get request, when I calling localhost from front-end